# Only choice for Desktop Environment Is Lubuntu in Wubi

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, wubi, lubuntu

Good morning,

after the release of 12.04, I tried to install Ubuntu on my laptop (Windows 7 Home, 4GB Ram, T6600, >80 GB free space on C) via wubi (downloaded from here: [Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)).
Previous experiences with 10.04 - 11.10 have always been positive.

After the download however, when presented with the installation dialog, the only option to pick when it comes to the DE is "Lubuntu", but I want to install Ubuntu.
On startup, Wubi identifies itself as "Ubuntu Installer for Windows"; when started it displays "Lubuntu Installation Programme" in  the window title.
Several test with wubi versions on the current Ubuntu CD as well as the Xubuntu CD yielded exactly the same result.

Fairly excessive googling has found nothing of interest for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I've experienced seems to be connected with the way wubi checks for available ISO images in the root directory of every mounted file system. 
Upon examining the log file wubi leaves behind, I found out wubi looks for ISOs in the root folder of any mounted file system except for C:\ (in a way assuming that anything else but C: is likely to be an optical drive containing a (K/X/L/you-name-it)Ubuntu CD).
There were several images for various Linux distributions on my external hard drive and wubi seems to have settled for the lubuntu one that was available.

In fact, wubi seems to have some kind of hierarchy in deciding which ISO is the one to be shown in the drop-down list if more than one is available (Lubuntu > Ubuntu > Xubuntu [haven't tried any other]).

Moving the ISOs to another directory (e.g. R:\isos) fixed the problem, now there is the full drop-down menu of DEs to choose from.

I hope this helps you, if you experience the same issue, which is, admittedly, very unlikely.